# How can I tell what was the payment method my customer chose during PayPal express checkout?

Tags: paypal, credit-card, express-checkout, payment-method

I'am about to implement PayPal's express checkout (client side).
**My questions is how can I tell what was the payment method my customer chose before?**

I was worked with express checkout a few years ago and it was easy. Right now, in every response I get "payment_method: paypal" no matter if I choose "paypal guest checkout" and use my credit card. I tried "everything" in the interactive demo and my implementation using the sandbox accounts:
I cannot find any difference in the execute response or in the payment details from I can tell the real payment method.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Why? What do you care what payment method was used, as long as you got the money?

Comment: It's about risk management...